# How to calculate and use keyboard height (in swift) in "textFieldDidBeginEditing" so that I can move UITextfield up precisely?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, notificationcenter

You can consider this as follow up question from my previous post.

I have coded a logic that would allow me to move textfield up whenever it is hidden behind the keyboard. As of now, I am considering keyboard will cover 40% of scree from bottom in all the devices and hence moving textfield as per the device size. This is of course a bad assumption and I need to first try to calculate the keyboard height and then apply the logic.

My research in stack overflow shown I can calculate the keyboard height using through Notification.

Though I wrote the logic for keyboard height following instruction from stack-overflow, I don't know how to merge my Notification code and textFieldDidBeginEditing together to get it run.

is there anyone who can one help me with this? in summary, I want to use keyboard height inside textFieldDidBeginEditing function to make it dynamic.

below is piece of codes I have written so far:

Keyboard height:

```
   func keyboardHeightNotification(){
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil
)
}


@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        print(keyboardHeight)
    }
}
```

Move text field up code (it is working fine but i need to incorporate keyboard heigh to make dynamic):

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField.frame.maxY > self.view.frame.height * 0.6
    {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: textField.frame.maxY - self.view.frame.height * 0.6 + 2.0), animated: true)

    }

    else{
        return
    }

    print(textField.frame.maxY)
    print(self.view.frame.height * 0.6)
    print(textField.frame.maxY - self.view.frame.height * 0.6)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

    self.view.endEditing(true);
}
```

updated code but still giving me an error:

```
 class StudentSignUpViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var yourEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var yourPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var joinUsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var back2SignInPage: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //setting portrait
    AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)

    //hide keyboard when click outside
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    //hide keyboard when click on return
    self.yourEmail.delegate = self
    self.yourPassword.delegate = self

    self.scrollView.delegate = self

    //boarder line for nameText

    //boarder line for yourEmail
    yourEmail.frame.size.height =  UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.05)
    yourEmail.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.04))
    bottomBoader(BottomLine: "UrEmailTextBottomLine", length: 1.0, yourTextBox: yourEmail)
    yourEmail.applyCustomClearButton(yourTextBox: yourEmail)

    //boarder line for yourPassword
    yourPassword.frame.size.height =  UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.05)
    yourPassword.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.04))
    bottomBoader(BottomLine: "UrPasswordTextBottomLine", length: 1.0, yourTextBox: yourPassword)
    yourPassword.applyCustomClearButton(yourTextBox: yourPassword)

    joinUsButton.layer.cornerRadius = joinUsButton.frame.height * 0.15
    back2SignInPage.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(0.03))


    keyboardHeightNotification()
    //textFieldDidBeginEditing(yourPassword)
    textFieldDidEndEditing(yourPassword)


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    keyboardHeightNotification()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
    keyboardHeightNotification()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    AppUtility.lockOrientation(.all)
}




// ********************************** move text up when keyboard present ****************************************

var kbHeight: CGFloat?

func keyboardHeightNotification(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil
    )
}


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

            if textField.frame.maxY > kbHeight!
            {
                self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: textField.frame.maxY - (kbHeight! + 2.0)), animated: true)

            }

            else{
                return
            }

            print(textField.frame.maxY)
            print(self.view.frame.height * 0.6)
            print(textField.frame.maxY - self.view.frame.height * 0.6)
        }
    }



}




func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

    self.view.endEditing(true);
}


}
```

Comment: When your keyboard appears when you edit your textField, your program calls textFieldDidBeginEditing and keyboardWillShow method ? Where do you add your notification observer ? Only on the  func keyboardHeightNotification() ? And you don't know where to place it right ?

Comment: Hi, I don’t know how to use height calculated in keyboardnotification in textFieldDidBeginEditing. Where and how should I place keyboardNotification so that use height variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party library for that, i use it constantly called `Typist` [link](https://github.com/totocaster/Typist) 
It's really simple to use and you can get a lot of information about the keyboard

To get the frame use like so:

`func startKeyboardListener() {
        keyboard
            .on(event: .didShow) { [weak self] (options) in
                self.setPosition(for:options.endFrame.origin.y)
            }
            .start()
    }`

Where `options.endFrame` is the keyboard frame you want. There is a lot of more useful information there

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your observer for the notification when your keyboard show on the lifecycle method `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`. Then, don't forget to remove your observer on the lifecycle method `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear`.

To get the keyboard height, why you create a global variable called `keyboardHeight` as an optional like this `var keyboardHeight: CGFloat? or Double?` .

Then your initialize this variable in your `keyboardWillShow` function. Finally, in your `textFieldDidEndEditing` function you can use your variable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. as per comment, I have created height variable and initialise it in keyboardWillShow. however, when I am using it in  textFieldDidEndEditing it is showing me an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

would you know what can I do to avoid it .. the code almost there but I just need to pass this last hurdle

Comment: Hum meaning that your keyboardWillShow happens after your textFieldDidEndEditing so your optional variable keyboardHeight is not initialised.

Comment: something similar .. I have pasted the updated code above in my original post

..any thoughts?

Comment: Alright. Can you move the code inside the textFieldDidBeginEditing into keyboardWillShow method ?

Comment: the error has gone but now scrollview is not moving up when textfield hides behind keyboard

Comment: Did you add the notification observer in viewDidAppear lifecycle method of your view controller ? If not your keyboardWillShow is never called

Comment: Hi, I am doing it .. I have saved whole code above for your reference ... thanks a lot for your help so far Bro

could you guess what I may be doing wrong looking at whole code ?

Comment: First you just need to add one time your keyboard height notification in your viewDidAppear. Then, don't put the whole textFieldDidBeginEditing in your keyboardWillShow function.

Comment: What i understood is .. I write textFieldDidBeginEditing separately as before (not inside the keyboardWillShow) than call keyboard height  notification only  in viewdDidAppear and then call   textFieldDidBeginEditing  only in viewDidLoad ... is that correct

Comment: Right except last one. In general as you implement uitextfieldDelegate you don't need to call explicitly textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Comment: thanks .. I will give it a shot once I reach home from my boring job

Comment: it didn't work .. I am now trying to different code found in stack overflow .. will update the answer if I succeeds

Answer (score 0):

// When Keyboard is Shown

**Add this code inside viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Create a global variable named **keyboardSize: CGRect?**

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            keyboardSize = keyboardFrame
        }
}
```

now you can use this **keyboardSize.height** or **keyboardSize.width** where ever you want.

but the problem is when you can textFieldBeginEditing for the first time, the value of keyboardSize will be nil, and it will crash.

What you can do it safely unwrap the optional. e.g

```
if let keyboardSize = keyboardSize {
     // This will help app not to crash
     // use keyboardSize inside this function.
}
```

*And to fix the problem that the keyboardSize wont have any value when you first tap on textField is, you can create a hidden textField somewhere and in viewDidLoad you make the textField firstResponder and then instantly removeFirstResponder.*